# Getting collection of elements from XML

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
   <author>
      <name />
   </author>
   <title>Publishing Point Collection</title>
   <updated>2013-01-14T15:58:44.589Z</updated>
   <entry>
      <id>http://example.com:80/test filename.isml/settings</id>
      <title>Test Title</title>
      <updated>2013-01-14T15:47:15Z</updated>
      <link href="http://example.com:80/test filename.isml/settings" rel="related" type="application/atom+xml" title="Settings" />
      <link href="http://example.com:80/test filename.isml/state" rel="related" type="application/atom+xml" title="State" />
      <link href="http://example.com:80/test filename.isml/statistics" rel="related" type="application/atom+xml" title="Statistics" />
   </entry>
</feed>
```

I'm loading the document by doing:

```
//xmlContent is the XML shown above.
XDocument publishingDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlContent);
```

I'm trying to get all of the link elements (specifically the href attribute, but, just the elements for now).  But, anytime I specify an XName I never get any results.  I've tried:

```
var data = publishingDocument.Elements("entry");
var data = publishingDocument.Elements("link").Attributes("href");
var data = publishingDocument.Root.Elements("entry");
```

None of these return any data.  I must be missing something very simple.

Comment: Try var data = publishingDocument.Descendants("link"). Elements(), I believe, only works on root level elements.

Comment: @Pete - Tried that.  I don't get any results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
var data = publishingDocument.Descendants(ns + "entry");
```